# Python: how to visualize the Minimum Spanning Tree of a network?

Tags: python, algorithm, plot, tree, networkx

I have a regular grid network made of `NxN` nodes. I am able to plot it, but I would also like to plot its [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm), which is a "subgraph that contains all the vertices and is a tree".

This is how I create the network:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import numpy
from numpy import *
import networkx as nx
from networkx import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=30
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
inds=labels.keys()
vals=labels.values()
inds.sort()
vals.sort()
pos2=dict(zip(vals,inds))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos2, with_labels=False, node_size = 15)
```

[image]

This is how I compute the Minimum Spanning Tree:

```
T=nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)
```

This generates a graph just like `G`, with the difference that `T` has the same nodes as `G` and a selection of its edges. Therefore, I would like to plot `T`, and this is what I did:

```
plt.figure()
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos2, with_labels=False, node_size = 15)
plt.show()
```

But I simply get the network plotted again. How can I amend the last lines to make sure my Minimum Spanning Tree is plotted?

Comment: pass T instead of G to the second draw_networkx?

Comment: I did a very stupid mistake. I apologise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plt.figure()
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos2, with_labels=False, node_size = 15)
plt.show()
```

should be

```
plt.figure()
nx.draw_networkx(T, pos=pos2, with_labels=False, node_size = 15)
plt.show()
```